# does tortoise orm load relations lazily or eagerly?

Tags: python, orm, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to find an async ORM that can load relations lazily.

my use case is a table with nested relations (at least 3 levels) that I want to load lazily only when needed in order to expose with strawberry graphQL.

at the moment I'm working with FastAPI and sqlalchemy, but it doesn't give a good solution for async programing and lazy loading.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by lazy loading? the django ORM only fetches related objects when you try to access them (or when using prefetch/select related) and I guess SQLAlchemy can do that too

Comment: @patrick I'm using FastAPI so my first try was with SQLAlchemy.

here you can see the loading policies with SQLAlchemy: 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html

the lazyload policy is not working well with async programming.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#running-synchronous-methods-and-functions-under-asyncio 

since I'm working with an async stack I'm using eager loading at the moment.

I saw tortoise ORM as an alternative. and I didn't fully manage to understand the loading policy that it use